# Two different lists from a tuple generator

Tags: python, python3

I have a generator, that yields me a tuple and a function that collects information from the generator and creates two separate lists:

```
labels = []
dataset = []
for data, label in list_data(folder):
    dataset.append(data)
    labels.append(label)
return dataset, labels
```

I'm not sure, if I'm not over-engineering here, but it feels like it's not the most pythonic way to solve it. 
I've tried some ideas with list comprehension, but it always resulted in syntax errors.

Or maybe is it the best solution as it ensures readability?

Comment: Yes there are super-clever ways to do it. But, six month from now, will you remember how to maintain those super-clever ways? Your current way is understandable and maintainable - nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a more Pythonic method of doing this exact interaction: [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
dataset, labels = zip(*list_data(folder))
```

The star (`*`) is important to tell `zip` to *unzip* the tuples of data.  In your function then, either return just `zip(*list_data(folder))` (no need for a for loop or the temporary variables, or simply use inline with no need for a function.

For future reference, note that this was more of a programming question, and thus likely better asked on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you. And you are definitely right, I was quite sure I was on the SO page, not AskUbuntu.